# How to create a Google Tag Manager trigger on a landing page with only javascript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Universal event tracking is already occurring with a GTM that is on every page. Knowing the GTM-XXXXXXX that exists on the site, how can javascript be used on a "thank you" page, the URL of which is known, to let us track how many people landed there after a successful form submission?

Please note that we do not have access to the Google account. We cannot set up anything or make any changes there, hence why we're being asked to code this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Data Layer to push events to the GTM. Here is a guide to run you through the process:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide